# Java: Calculate sum of continuously printed numbers from InputStreamReader every n seconds?

Tags: java, string, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm using InputStreamReader to retrieve values from a shell terminal that produces an output constantly while running.

Right now, I am printing the result to the console by using substring: `System.out.println(inputStr.substring(inputStr.lastIndexOf(" ")+1));`, as it will print the last digits of the output which I need.

With an output running continously with perhaps 1 print per second, how do I wrote Java code to sum of all the printed numbers every N seconds?(let's say 20 seconds for good measure)?

Here's the sourcecode so far:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class fooShell {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        while(true){
            try {
                String inputStr = bufReader.readLine();
                if(inputStr == null) {
                    break;
                }
                    System.out.println(inputStr.substring(inputStr.lastIndexOf(" ")+1));     
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error "+e);
            }
        }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the continually updated sum as a class variable and update it each time you poll the InputStreamReader.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FooShell
{
  int runningTotal;

  FooShell()
  {
    runningTotal = 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    FooShell fooShell = new FooShell();
    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
    while (true)
    {
      try
      {
        String inputStr = bufReader.readLine();
        if (inputStr == null)
        {
          break;
        }
        int currentNumber = Integer
            .parseInt(inputStr.substring(inputStr.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1));
        fooShell.runningTotal += currentNumber;
        System.out.println(currentNumber);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.err.println("Error " + e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you have this inside the main? Also, how would you make it print the sum every N seconds? Also I don't see you using the "MyClass" value ever?

Comment: Without a clue what your code looks like, it is very difficult to give you more direction. Wherever your code is currently that is printing the result to the console just needs to update a sum variable. MyClass is a generic classname not a value to be used.